# TYPO3 fluid template: Submitting multiple objects to the action?

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

In a f:form is it possible to pass 2 or more objects to the corresponding action? Because i need to pass another object through to the next action, which get's both objects as parameters in turn.

So far the form looks like this (with just the one object):

```
<f:form action="addchob" name="newChob" object="{newChob}" >



        <f:form.textfield property="name" value="1" /><br />
        <f:form.checkbox property="checked" value="1" checked="0" /><br />



<br />



<br />
<f:form.submit value="Save" />
</f:form>
```

The problem is, that i cannot access the old object in the "addChob" action, but i need it as it holds the Object Storage for the "newChob" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define arguments in the FormViewHelper:

```
<f:form action="addchob" name="newChob" object="{newChob}" arguments="{argumentA:argumentA, argumentB:argumentB}">
```

These arguments are attached to the action url.

Comment: This solution works like a champ and definitely better than my other approach, using a session variable.